# Linear Algebra (vector spaces axioms)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with zero element $0$ and let $v \in V$

$1$. Show that if $av=0$ then  either $a=0$ or $v=0$

$2$. Show that if $av=bv$ and $v \neq 0$, then $a= b$

What i tried

For the first part. I prove by contradiction Taking the negation i have,  $av=0$ and both $a\neq0$ and $v\neq0$

Then i multiply both sides of the equation $av=0$ by $1/a$ to get $v=0.(1/a)$ and hence $v=0$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $v\neq0$. Hence proving the theorem above.

For the second part i again use a prove by contradiction by assuming that that $av=bv$ and $v\neq0$ and $a\neq b$. Thus $a-b\neq 0$ and subtracting $bv$ on both sides of the equation $av=bv$ i get $av-bv=0$ by distributive law this becomes $v(a-b)=0$ Since from a property from a vector   space i know that $v0=0$ for any vector space $v$ then $a-b$ must be $0$ hence contradiction the fact that $a-b\neq 0 $ Hence proving the statement above.

Is my solution correct. Could anyone explain Thanks. Also when dealing with questions on properties on vector spaces. Can i treat those property of vectors spaces as though it is similar to properties of arithmetic? Which are the properties of vector spaces that differs from property of arithmetic that i have to take note of?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are correct but I have two suggestions:

1. You don't need a contradiction for the first part. You just say suppose $a\ne 0$. Then, just as you said, you can multiply through by $a^{-1}$ to get $v=0$. You get the same proof but without a contradiction.
2. For the second part, leverage the result from the first part. If $av=bv$ then $av-bv=(a-b)v=0$ and if $v\ne 0$, by part 1, $(a-b)=0\implies a=b$